# How can I get the EnvDTE.Document associated with a IWpfTextView?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, envdte

I have a `IWpfTextViewConnectionListener` based extension. I need access to the `EnvDTE.Document` associated with the `IWpfTextView` I'm being given. I've tried storing `_DTE.ActiveDocument`, but this only works on files that were not already open previously (if the file was open already, it's `null`).

How can I get the document object for the text view that is showing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an `IWpfTextView.TextBuffer`, you can get the `ITextBuffer`.  From that, you can use `ITextDocumentFactoryService.TryGetTextDocument()` to get the matching `ITextDocument`, if one exists.  Then, `ITextDocument.FilePath` gives you the path to the file.

You can then enumerate through the `DTE2.Documents` collection to find the open document with the same path.

More on `ITextDocumentFactoryService`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextdocumentfactoryservice.aspx